# What options should i use during gcc (mingw) configuration to build libstdc++.dll without debugging information?

Tags: gcc, mingw

I configured gcc as follows:

> ../configure
>   --prefix=/c/mbuild/release **--enable-shared=libstdc++** --enable-threads --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-win32-registry --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-gmp=/c/mbuild/release --with-ppl=/c/mbuild/release --disable-ppl-version-check --with-cloog=/c/mbuild/release --disable-cloog-version-check --with-mpfr=/c/mbuild/release --with-mpc=/c/mbuild/release --enable-libgomp --with-libiconv-prefix=/c/mbuild/release
>   **--enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-cxx-flags='-s -O2'** **--with-boot-ldflags='-s'** **--with-boot-cflags='-s -O2' --with-boot-cxxflags='-s -O2**' &>config.my.log

and build:

> make -j4 BOOT_CFLAGS='-s -O2' 
>   BOOT_CPPFLAGS='-s -O2' &>make.my.log

I've got everything optimized, except libstdc++-6.dll. It size is 5Mb!
So... What options should i use during gcc (mingw) configuration to build libstdc++.dll without debugging information?

**NOTE:**
I need debug and release versions of libstdc++, so I'm using
*--enable-libstdcxx-debug* - Build separate debug libraries **in addition** to what is normally built.
This flag makes another libstdc++-6.dll (somwhere in lib dir), wich is larger, than dll in the bin dir.

Comment: You should be able to call the `strip` command after the fact (do save the original lib and read the doc, it may take a few tries to get the right options).

Comment: FYI: I have not seen any official documentation around `BOOT_CPPFLAGS` or `BOOT_CXXFLAGS` -- only `BOOT_CFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass strip option to linker, not to compiler (-s). And to compiler you should pass "-g -O0" for debug build, which means include debug information + stright code generation without any optimization (the last one is for case you read disasm code, it makes stuff clearer). So, try adding to LDFLAGS environment variable -s option for build time.

As an alternative, you could use "strip" program (part of MSYS) to strip all debug info from executable and/or library binary file.

Comment: If you look more careful, you'll see "-with-boot-ldflags='-s'" option in configuration. It doesn't helps. I think "-g" will do the trick, but unfortunatelly I can't test this. The problem is not actual. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but could this binary fat be due to some implicit static linkage?